# Errors in trying to upload documents with titles in other languages to document library using powershell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-2010

I have a powershell script which uploads resumes from a resume folder on the server to the document library.

However, I am facing a problem wherein the names of the resumes are in different languages and I can not figure out how to handle the exception as there are 13 different languages in which the resumes exist. I was tempted to try something alike  :

```
 [System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex] $RgxUrl ="[\?\/{|}~]"
```

just passing the special characters like 'ê' etc specific to languages instead of "\" "?" etc
and then setting a new title for the file, but I realized that since there are 13 different languages this will be a herculean task. Is there any other better way to handle this situation?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

How about using [`System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urlencode.aspx)? Like so,

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Web # Load assebly for Httputility
[Web.HttpUtility]::UrlEncode("Montréal") # Test string with é
[Web.HttpUtility]::UrlEncode("Citroën") # Test string with ë

# Outputs:
Montr%c3%a9al
Citro%c3%abn
```

And the way back:

```
[Web.Httputility]::UrlDecode("Citro%c3%abn")
[Web.Httputility]::UrlDecode("Montr%c3%a9al")
# Outputs:
Citroën
Montréal
```